# Restore windows 10 system image taken from another PC

Tags: windows-10

I have full windows 10 system image created from my office PC to an external drive. I would like to have same setup on my laptop as well. When I click on restore system image, windows 10 setup says no system image found but it's there in the external drive! I renamed my laptop name to match my PC name but it didn't help. I guess system image is locked to current hardware but I am not sure. Called Microsoft but they have dumbs sittings there and they didn't understand my question. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question either. Could you be more specific as to how you created the backup, how you are restoring, and the exact error message (or even a screenshot of it).

Comment: Windows image backup is hardware dependent, it will not image to a different PC, you would need to use third party image software to do that.

Comment: If you could restore a Windows install image to a different machine, (a) it would likely crash due to hardware differences (b) you would be in violation of the Windows EULA.

Comment: How about reinstall the home PC with the office PC image.

Comment: Not sure why 2 downvotes on my question? Down vote without explanation makes no sense.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have two license and it does not violate any windows policy. Regarding hardware difference windows is now smart enough to detect and install hardwares. I switched hard drives between PCs and it works fine!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

1. Installed EaseUs Todo backup on my office computer
2. Took full system image (sector by sector)
3. Created WinPE recovery usb disk from the EaseUS Software->tools
4. Boot my laptop from usb
5. Restored system image.